# deploying java web app to heroku: "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, maven, heroku, deployment, heroku-ci

I followed this instruction:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java

to deploy a java web app to heroku.

The content of my Procfile is the following:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Optimizer
```

(Optimizer is the name of my main class.)

Executing the command

```
mvn clean install
```

builds the project successfully.

But then executing the command

```
heroku local web
```

results in the following error message:

```
web.1 |  Error: Could not find or load main class Optimizer
```

Does anybody have any idea what I need to do differently?

Comment: Hard to say with the limited information. Does `Optimizer` really live outside of any package?

Comment: No it doesn’t.... it’s in package com.michael.optimizer .... given this fact, what should the procfile look like?

Comment: `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.michael.optimizer.Optimizer`

Should work in that case. Let me know if that fixes your issue! :)

Comment: yes, thank you. the error message is gone.